# How to use django ORM for dynamic binding relation?

Tags: django, orm

Well, this is the problem, I have a username column and I defined it in the models.py.
And a user may take some courses( the course may changes in the future), the relation between user and courses is 1 vs multi, which means a user can take multi courses and a courses could be taken by several users.
I am new to django and DB design, how to represent this in Django with ORM?

```
def user(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class courses(models.Model):
    course = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Show your model definitions please.

Comment: Sounds like you need a many to many relationship. Have a look here for starters https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @djsutho thought, define a [many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):

```
class user(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(courses)

class courses(models.Model):
    course = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Then, for example, querying courses per user would be as easy as:

```
courses.objects.filter(user__name='Bob')
```

Also note that, by [Django model naming convention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style), model class names should start with a upper case letter: `user` should be `User`, `courses` - `Courses`.

Also note that the model name should not be in a plural form - better name `courses` as `Course`. Also better rename `course` field to `name`.

So, finally, here's the picture:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course)

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Hope that helps.